# OpenGL fade issue

Tags: c++, opengl, fade

This is what I'm doing:

- Render the first image using a color of: `glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);`
- Render the second image, using a color of: `glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, calc);`. `calc` is a number that goes from 0.0 to 1.0 within a second, and I can verify that it does actually do this.

What I expect it to do is to fade from one image to the other, and it does this, but halfway through, it goes into some kind of shade of grey (black is the background color, btw). You can see the issue here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dZXiYIM43s&feature=youtu.be .

I just want the basic fade, **WITHOUT** the greyish tone when in the middle of fading (which is the strongest at 0.5 opacity). I've tried doing this with GIMP, bottom layer is opaque, top layer is variable opacity, and it works fine, it does *exactly* what I want it to do, I just don't know why my code (or OpenGL) won't do the same. A video demonstrating what I mean: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ym-VPu9hhjQ&feature=youtu.be

**EDIT**: After a bit of experimentation (changing the background color to red), at 0.5, it becomes translucent, which would normally be the effect wanted, except that *BOTH* texture are translucent (not just the one on top). Why does this happen??

Here is the code:

```
void Sprite::render_single(Image* image, Pos2D pos, Angle angle) {
        int cx = image->width / 2;
        int cy = image->height / 2;
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(pos.x + cx, pos.y + cy, 0);
        glRotatef(angle.to_degrees(), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glTranslatef(-cx, -cy, 0);
        image->bind();
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
                glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);
                glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
                glVertex2f(image->width, 0.0);
                glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
                glVertex2f(image->width, image->height);
                glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
                glVertex2f(0.0, image->height);
        glEnd();
        image->unbind();
        glPopMatrix();
}

void Sprite::render(Pos2D pos, Angle angle) {
        Image* img = this->get_current_frame();
        if (this->images.size() == 1) {
                this->render_single(img, pos, angle);
                return;
        }
        double calc = (((double)this->current_frame_overflow) / this->frame_length);
        std::cout << calc << std::endl;
        glPushMatrix();
        glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        this->render_single(img, pos, angle);
        img = this->get_next_frame();
        glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, calc);
        this->render_single(img, pos, angle);
        glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glPopMatrix();
}
```

Blend function used: `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

OpenGL initialization function:

```
/**
 * @brief Initializes OpenGL
 */
void Game::init_gl() {
        float width = this->display->w;
        float height = this->display->h;
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluOrtho2D(0.0, width, height, 0.0);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}
```

Also, here is the whole source code for the main loop (which contains most of the OpenGL stuff): https://github.com/MiJyn/dbab/blob/master/src/game.cpp . And the sprite: https://github.com/MiJyn/dbab/blob/master/src/sprite.cpp .

Comment: They video helps but we don't know what you are actually trying to do. How it should look?

Comment: @Trax, thanks, I _knew_ there was something I forgot... I added it in the post :)

Comment: have you tried with blend(ONE, ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)? This is what an image editor will do by default, which is "sum" both layers (background is opaque + top semi-transparent one).

Comment: @Trax, yes, but then it starts looking _really_ odd (the whole game does, and though I don't have the issue, it seems to layer or something... it's very odd)... using `GL_SRC_ALPHA` instead of `GL_ONE` works fine, but it my issue still remains

Comment: My bad, I just woke up, it is (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE), but after using it you should go back to your previous setup, otherwise this blending function is used across all your objects.

Comment: @Trax, oh ok, and no, that doesn't work either. When `calc` reaches 1, it goes much brighter than when it was at 0. In GIMP, the lumination stays the same

Comment: @Trax I added a new video, showing what I _want_ it to look like

Comment: It may be due to wrong texture (are you sure the texture has alpha 1 at brackground areas?). Remove everything else from rendering, only do that effect and only that. Check if it works then, other rendering code may be changing states.

Comment: @Trax, I removed everything, and the issue _still_ remains

Comment: Do you have alpha test enabled?

Comment: @FullFrontalNudity No, I don't. Should I? And what function should I use if so?

Comment: Alpha test discards certain fragments based on a function of that fragment's alpha. So it's only a problem if you have it enabled, you should have it disabled in this case.
As a side note, try disabling depth test when you draw the alpha images.

Comment: @FullFrontalNudity, There is no depth test either (it's never enabled in the program)

Comment: It may be necessary to see more of the gl-related code.  From what you've shown, it looks correct, and the (src_alpha, one_minus_src_alpha) is the correct function for what you're trying to do.  Worst case scenario, you could disable blending for the first draw and re-enable for the second.

Comment: @JonathanChandler I did so, is that enough? Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @JonathanChandler, also, I tried disabling blending for the first draw, and re-enabling for the second, with _still_ the same issue!

Comment: Your sprite.cpp source on github has a glPushAttrib for GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT , I don't know what this does from experience but according to http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glPushAttrib.xml it enables the GL_ALPHA_TEST bit along with other attributes (or I misunderstand documentation). Can you explain?

Comment: @FullFrontalNudity, If I'm correct, it's similar to `glPushMatrix`, except that it works for attributes. I might be wrong though. I'll try removing it, and seeing if it works. **EDIT**: Nope, same issue

Comment: I've upvoted your question, I can't figure it out :(. The thing I do as a last resort is throw in alot of glEnable/glDisable and move your glColor statements all over the place till it works, then figure out why it works. Good luck. Also, I'd advise you to clean up your main render loop, it will make your life easier in the future.

Comment: What are you rendering into? If you are rendering into a buffer with an alpha channel your second draw might be writing to the buffer's alpha. Then when the buffer is drawn to the device this alpha is being used to blend the final image.

Comment: Just to add to my last comment - even if you are not explicitly rendering to an FBO, your OpenGL context might use a buffer (with alpha) and composite it using alpha to the device (IIRC the Rasperry Pi's context works like this). You could try glColorMask(1,1,1,0) to test this.

Comment: @FullFrontalNudity, I'd almost do that... but I think that it would take more time than it is worth (last resort is to use shaders). And yes, that's exactly what I'm doing while I'm waiting for an answer :)

Comment: @GuyRT, it's rendering to an FBO (if you're wondering, here is the source: https://github.com/MiJyn/dbab/blob/master/src/postprocess.cpp). How would I fix that then?

Comment: Since the creation/use of the FBO is under your control, I think the easiest way would be to remove the alpha channel from the texture you use in your FBO (use GL_RGB instead of GL_RGBA for the third parameter of glTexImage2D in Post::Post()). If you need alpha in your FBO texture, another option would be to use glBlendFuncSeparate instead of glBlendFunc or as I said above use glColorMask to avoid writing to the alpha channel.

Comment: Another thought: disable blending - glDisable(GL_BLEND) - in your Post::render() function.

Comment: @GuyRT, Thanks, using `glDisable(GL_BLEND)` works!! Could you convert it to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `glBlendFunc` function (with blending enabled) the same factors are used to calculate the alpha value of the destination fragment.

This only matters if you are rendering to a texture which has an alpha channel and subsequently using that texture with blending enabled. In this case, the alpha channel of the rendered texture ends up with values between zero and one. This causes some of the background to bleed through when the texture is drawn to the back buffer.

The solution is simply to disable blending when drawing the full-screen quad. Also, you might as well remove the channel from the texture if you're not using it (use `GL_RGB` instead of `GL_RGBA` for the internal texture format).

Answer (score 0):

Grey fringing is a side effect of not using pre-multiplied alpha.

Try using `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` to enable pre-multiplied alpha. Look up premultiplication for more information, but basically all your textures and colors need to be premultiplied. In short you go through every pixel and color and multiply the r, g and b by a. So where you would have 50% white as (1, 1, 1, 0.5), it now becomes (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5).  In this case your target color will also need to be (calc, calc, calc, calc).

Comment: I tried this, but then a different effect happens. At first, the texture becomes abnormally bright, and at the end, it finally goes to the normal brightness. I tried both using the call before the function, and in  the middle (after rendering the first one)

Comment: Also, another question: Wouldn't (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5) be (too much) more transparent than (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5)? Or am I not understanding you correctly?